# Limit Distributions of Maxima and integral

Tags: probability-limit-theorems, order-statistics

We assume that the CDF of some distribution $F_{X_k}(x)$ for $k=1,2,\cdots,K$.
And that $X_k$ for all $k$ are mutually independent. Let us denote $X_{\max} = \max_{k=1,2\cdots,K}\{X_k\}$. Then the CDF of $X_{\max}$ is given by $F_{X_{\max}}(x) = \prod^{K}_{k=1}F_{X_k}(x)$.

$$\lim_{K\rightarrow \infty}\int^\infty_{-\infty}F_{X_{max}}(x)dx = 
\int^\infty_{-\infty}\lim_{K\rightarrow \infty}F_{X_{max}}(x)dx =
0$$

Can you prove the above equation?

Comment: Any distribution function $F$ is positive nondecreasing and tends to $1$ when $x\to\infty$, so $F(x)\geq F(x_0)>0$ if $x\geq x_0$ for some $x_0$, and then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)\,dx\geq\int_{x_0}^\infty F(x_0)\,dx=\infty$. That strongly disagrees with what you are trying to show. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion.
The range of  all random variable $X_k$ is $0 \leq X_k < 1$.
$E[X_{max}] = \int^1_0 1 - (F_{X_k}(x))^Kdx$.
Then,  $\lim_{K\rightarrow\infty}E[X_{max}] = 1$.
Actually, my question is above equation.

Answer (score 1):

Define $$f_K(x):=F-F^{K+1}_{X_\max}(x)$$ Since $F_{X_k}(x)\le 1$ for any $x\in \mathbb R$, you have that $$F^K_{X_\max}(x)=\prod_{k=1}^KF_{X_k}(x)\le \prod_{k=1}^{K+1}F_{X_k}(x)=F^{K+1}_{X_\max}(x)$$ Hence $0\le f_K(x)\le f_{K+1}(x)\le +\infty$. Moreover $$\lim_{K\to \infty}f_K(x)=0$$ for any $x\in\mathbb R. Hence, you may apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem to interchange the limit with the integral.

Comment: Please see my comment above. Also you forgot to close the dollar sign at the end of your answer.